# jQuery: JSON.parse doesn't work for a long JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I am downloading a large text file from a server to a phonegap app. The text is valid JSON in string form. I write the text data to the device's file system, then read it later. I fetch the text data using the filereader adn this seems to work fine. Its when I parse the string JSON that the problem occurs.

When I download a text file containing 2500 elements(records returned from a DB and returned in json format) the JSON.parse(stringJSON) function works fine and returns a JSON object, however if I increase the number of elements returned from the server to 3000 then I get no response, teh json output seems to be formatted correctly. It looks like a memory problem, the JSON data is at most 1.5MB, is that too much to parse using jquery's JSON.parse, with phonegap. I looked at [this](http://rickluna.com/wp/2013/04/jquery-parsejson-vs-json-parse-vs-json_parse-memory-profiles-during-jsonp-ajax-requests/) page and tried including parse_json instead of JSON.parse and it still returns nothing (I included the relevant script in my page).

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();

 ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var perc = Math.abs(Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100));
        $loading.html(perc + " Loading...")
    } else {
        if($loading.innerHTML == "") {
            $loading.innerHTML = "Loading";
        } else {
            $loading.innerHTML += ".";
        }
    }
};

var dlPath = DATADIR_separate.fullPath + "/"+foldername_separate+".html";
ft.download("http://downloadURL", dlPath, function(){
    alert('saved');
    $loading.hide();
    remove_permanent_overlay();
}, function(){
    alert('fail');
    $loading.hide();
    remove_permanent_overlay();
});
```

then after all the file reader callbacks:

```
function readAsText_READ(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    alert('loaded');//this fires, so filereader is working
    //alert(evt.target.result);//this alerts even with a large string
    //var parseTarget = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);//works for smaller strings fails with larger strings
    console.log('parsing now...');
    var parseTarget = json_parse(evt.target.result);//same result as JSON.parse
    console.log(parseTarget);
    //var parseTarget = $.parseJSON( evt.target.result );
    //var parseTarget = eval( "("+evt.target.result+")" );
    //alert(parseTarget);
    alert(parseTarget["879"]);
};

reader.readAsText(file);
//reader.readAsDataURL(file)
alert('reading file: '+file);
```

}

*Edit
In phonegap's weinre debugger I get the following when I try to read the large json string.

```
parsing...
processMessage failed: Message: S01 File1238321490
s{"really long json... jsonetc..."}
processMessage failed: Error: [object Object]
processMessage failed: Stack: undefined
```

not quite sure what those error messages mean, I'll try find out...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without showing an error message it is hard to guess.

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question with the output I got from the weinre console, not sure how helpful it is.

Comment: you should catch the error thrown by `json_parse` e.g. with `try { var parseTarget = json_parse(evt.target.result); } catch( e  ) { console.dir(e) }` to see if it is the parser and what message it shows.

Comment: I tried the try catch, and got exactly the same error message, with no additional errors output to the console, so I guess that means that there's no problem with json_parse?

Comment: Without having the code in front it is not easy to tell. If calling the `json_parse` would not throw an error, then the problem seems to be somewhere else. Does probably your `console.log(parseTarget);` fail?

Comment: after json_parse(evt.target.result) there's no response, so the console.log(parseTarget) doesn't return anything. I think there's a memory problem, I suspect that the 1.5MB string is put into memory and then parsed and that's the problem. Anyway I was hoping it was something obvious that I was missing but I guess not... I'll keep battling this and post back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for some closure:

I reduced the size of the file to be downloaded and stupidly I forgot to escape the content being sent from the server to the mobile app, so it was receiving invalid JSON. This was hard to discover since the first few thousand entries in the JSON were valid, there were a few rogue double quotes later in the string.

I escaped the content from the server and easily managed to parse the JSON in a 300kb file. I'm pretty sure a 1MB file would also work fine.